# Hide terminal, C + GTK

Tags: c, macos, gtk

```
gcc -o program program.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
```

When I run the program, it show both the GUI and the terminal. How can I hide the terminal?

Comment: This link will help with your platform issues: http://www.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can double click on the executable named "program". Then you will not see the terminal.

Comment: I have the same problem as he describes - launching the program this way is what's causing the problem, not the solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

add -mwindows parameter to compiler command line

Comment: Based on the "mac" tag I assume it's not Windows, so this probably wouldn't work.